# How to configure SpotBugs maven plugin to create a full report but check for high threshold only?

Tags: maven, static-analysis, spotbugs

I have a legacy maven project and want to integrate the *FindBugs* successor *SpotBugs* to create a report of all issues but fail if there a **High** priority issues only (for now).

It is easy to create the report only without fail ing **or** to fail on a specific threshold. But when specifying a threshold all issues below that one are also removed from the report.

I have tried to configure the plugin according to to [documentation](https://spotbugs.github.io/spotbugs-maven-plugin/examples/violationChecking.html) but without success:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
  <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <effort>Max</effort>
    <threshold>High</threshold>
    <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
    <spotbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/spotbugs-reports</spotbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
    <xmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/spotbugs-reports</xmlOutputDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I am using Maven 3 and SpotBugs 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that helps, it's mostly a workaround.

I have a similar case and what I did was that I placed the configuration in a "reporting" tag (not reportSets). In the "build" tag, I just put the plugin information and the dependencies. The configuration used the default values for the output xml and output folder. I also added file which was filtering out some of the bugs:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.10</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.11</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludeFilterFile>spotbugs_filter.xml</excludeFilterFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

I then did a

```
mvn clean install site spotbugs:check
```

This gave me:

- a spotbugsXml.xml file in the build_directory containing ALL of the bugs found (no filters applied).
- a report spotbugs.html was produced in target/site which contained the filtered list of bugs.

So, to link this with your issue, I guess that using these "steps" you can have two reports, one with the threshold and another one without.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks, but I need a full report/xml but the check goal to fail only for high prio findings.

Comment: were you able to find how to fail the build on high priority bugs?